# Dexguard: Encrypting .so files without the Android application

Tags: android, java-native-interface, obfuscation, dexguard

Currently I have a simple android library. I am able to perform obfuscation with DexGuard. But now I want to use DexGuard's native library encryption feature without actually having an Android application. Is it possible to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found out the solution

```
-injars ./libhello-jni.zip
-injars ./myjar.jar
-encryptnativelibraries lib/**/*.so
```

Important points:

- `libhello-jni.zip` should contain a `lib` folder containing the `*.so` files
- Somewhere in the code in `myjar.jar` it should be using the class which calls the `System.loadLibrary("hello-jni")` so DexGuard can successfully encrypt the `*.so` files